# Random partial black screen appear on my flutter app (observed only with iOS device)

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a bug of partial (99%) black screen, who is not closable, need restart app..

I have no container with this ratio, no black screen, It's appear rarely and randomly, even if user don't touch screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?